# How to change the language localization in Stripe framework?

Tags: swift, localization, stripe-payments

I added Stripe payment to my app, and adding cards using STPAddCardViewController. I need to show STPAddCardViewController navigation items like Cancel, Add a Card, Done in French.

I seen that there is localisation for Various languages in Stripe which I have installed through pod. But I don't find right way to apply the French localisation for STPAddCardViewController

Comment: check NSLocalizedString properties

Comment: Can you verify that the device/simulator has the [correct settings for localization](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SpecifyingPreferences/SpecifyingPreferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH12-SW1)?